# Video Overlay System with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a video overlay solution such as this one: https://www.videologixinc.com/, where there is no delay in the original source video.

My problem is that, with OpenCV, all the necessary drawings (circle, text, etc) requires the entire frame to be processed and then returned to be exhibited. Is there any solution where I could just overlay the information in the original source without implying in delay/frame drop? (the additional information can be displayed with delay - drawings, text - but not the original video pipeline).
Multiprocessing could make things faster, but I would still have delay or frame drops.

I was also thinking if would be better to have two simultaneous applications and maybe two different computers - one to read the frame and make the processing - and another one to just receive, somehow, the information to overlay it on the original video pipeline.

Any thoughts? Thank you all!

[An example of data pipeline in this case, without interfering in the original video flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvbf9.png)

Comment: Try drawing all your text and graphics on a blank image and then copy on top of the current frame using a mask.

Comment: @asif thank you for your answer! This is what I am doing already, but I still have to deal with the delay of applying the mask frame-by-frame, instead of just overlay it to the live stream.